# Load axios data in vue apexcharts

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, apexcharts

As title, I'm trying to load Axios data in Vue apexcharts (line chart) using vue2.
I've read the apexcharts' document, but still can't figure out how to pass the data into the chart. I would like to have the date as x-axis, and others as values in the line chart.

Also, I've checked in vue devtools, it seems that the data is passed successfully?
[image]

My data format is like this:

```
follower = [
  {
    date: '2021-11-10',
    follower: 2000,
    following: 500,
    media: 150
  }
  {
    date: '2021-11-11',
    follower: 2000,
    following: 500,
    media: 150
  }
]
```

My chart initialization:

```
 <template>
   <apexchart
     ref="sample"
     width="500"
     type="area"
     :options="chartOptions"
     :series="series"
  >
  </apexchart>
 </template>

export default {
  name: "FollowerLineApex",
  components: {
    apexcharts: VueApexCharts,
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      series: [{
        name: 'test',
        data: []
      }],
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          height: 350,
          type: 'area',
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Example-1',
        },
        xaxis: {
          type: "datetime"
        },
     }
  }
```

},

Below is my code in Axios part:

```
created: function () {
  this.getData()
},

methods: {
  getData() {
    this.$axios.get('/api/')
        .then(res => {
          this.series = [{
            data: res.data["follower"]
          }]
          console.log(this.series)
          this.$refs.sample.updateOptions({
            series: [{
              data: this.series
            }]
          })
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        })
  }
},
```

Comment: Is this vue 2 or vue 3?

Comment: I'm using vue2. I'll add on in the article, thanks for reminding me!

Comment: Out of the 3 data points (`follower`, `following` and `media`), how do you want them charted? Are they meant to be separate series?

Comment: I would like to have each date display these 3 data points together. Like the line chart in the link: https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/line-charts/data-labels/

Comment: Just go through the documents again. And yes, I think the 3 data points should be separate series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data isn't formatted correctly. You need to format the data you get from your api before you pass it to your chart's series. Your `datetime` xaxis chart should be formatted as an array of x,y coordinates. Described here https://apexcharts.com/docs/series/

**Example:**

```
  [
    {
      x: 10,
      y: 20,
    },
    {
      x: 100,
      y: 50,
    },
  ]
```

**Working sandbox example**

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-basic-example-forked-r26j6?file=/src/components/Chart.component.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="app">
    <apexcharts
      width="500"
      height="350"
      type="area"
      :options="chartOptions"
      :series="series"
    ></apexcharts>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueApexCharts from "vue-apexcharts";

export default {
  name: "Chart",
  components: {
    apexcharts: VueApexCharts,
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      follower: [
        {
          date: "2021-11-10",
          follower: 2000,
          following: 500,
          media: 150,
        },
        {
          date: "2021-11-11",
          follower: 2000,
          following: 500,
          media: 30,
        },
      ],
      series: [
        {
          name: "test",
          data: [],
        },
      ],
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          height: 350,
          type: "area",
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
        },
        title: {
          text: "Example-1",
        },
        xaxis: {
          type: "datetime",
        },
      },
    };
  },
  created: function () {
    this.getData();
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
      
      // TODO Axios to get data here.

      // Format data correctly
      let formattedData = this.follower.map((e, i) => {
        return {
          x: e.date,
          y: e.media,
        };
      });

      // update the series with axios data
      this.series = [
        {
          name: "test",
          data: formattedData,
        },
      ];      
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've registered the `VueApexCharts` component as `apexcharts` (plural) so you should either be using `<apexcharts>` (plural) in your template or register it as `apexchart`...

```js
components: {
  apexchart: VueApexCharts
}
```

As per [the documentation](https://apexcharts.com/docs/vue-charts/#updating), you do not need to manually call `updateOptions`...

> Updating your Vue chart data is simple. You just have to update the series props which you pass to the `<apexchart>` component and it will automatically trigger event to update the chart.

What you do need to do though is format the data into something the chart can use

```js
data: () => ({
  followerData: [],
  chartOptions: { /* same as you already have */ }
}),
computed: {
  // compute series data from you API results
  series: ({ followerData }) => {
    const series = followerData.reduce((map, { date, ...points }) => {
      Object.entries(points).forEach(([ name, point ]) => {
        const s = (map.has(name) ? map : map.set(name, [])).get(name)
    
        s.push({
          x: date,
          y: point
        })
      })
      return map
    }, new Map())

    return Array.from(series.entries(), ([ name, data ]) => ({
      name,
      data
    }))
  }
},
methods: {
  async getData() {
    const { data } = await this.$axios.get("/api/")
    this.followerData = data
  }
},
created () {
  this.getData()
}
```